# Require_once triggering on page load and when submit?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page (horses.php) that includes:

```
 <?php require_once('send_email.php');?>
```

What happens is I have some scripting to send an email (and do some other things) in the send_email.php file.

Now when horses.php loads the send_email.php page triggers and sends an email. It works perfectly. But on horses.php I also have a submit button that updates a db and goes to anoher page.. But what happens is that the send_email.php seems to be triggered on page load and also on submit? Because I get an email on page load (as I should), but then also when I press submit??

Ideas around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try only sending the email if the form hasn't been submitted:

```
if (!isset($_POST['name_of_an_element_in_the_form'])) {
  require_once('send_email.php');
}
```

Comment: @user718359 I think you are missing his point. He is basically suggesting you check to see if form has not been submitted yet. If it hasn't been submitted yet then that would indicate you are arriving at the page for the first time (based on the logic you have described). If that is the case then your `require_once` will trigger the email code.

Comment: But they have to submit once on horse.php to get to the next page.. so it will be submitted..

Comment: Some where along the line "horses.php" is being loaded twice. The submitted button is likely just the trigger causing it to be loaded twice. Perhaps you left out the `action` attribute of your form the submit button is attached to and is therefore using the default action of sending the form submission to itself thus causing the page to be loaded a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You have some code to send a mail while loading send_email.php ? I don't think it's a good practice, just define a function (or a class) to send a mail in send_email.php and call it when you actually need to send a mail...

Comment: Na - when loading horses.php.. the code is all in send_email.php to actually send the relevant email etc..